# Late 2013 MacBook Pro subject to frequent crashing

Tags: macbook-pro, crash

My late 2013 MacBook Pro has began crashing frequently, sometimes when it is just "idling", and sometimes when I am Word Processing.

Here are some of the things that I have noticed.

- This happens more often when the computer is not plugged in, but the battery still has a respectable 70% charge.
- There is nothing obvious in any of the log files.
- When it happens one of two things will happen: The screen will freeze, and after around 20 seconds the machine will power off; Or, the screen will suddenly go black and the fans spin like crazy, someone commented yesterday that they thought that the noise was coming from the heating system.

Someone, suggested that I try resetting the NVPRAM and SMC, both of which I tried to no avail. I also tried reinstalling the machine from scratch and while this seemed to fix the problem for a short while (one or two days) the problem is back, albeit less frequent now.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can resolve this issue?

Hardware Information:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013)
- 1 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 (i7-4850HQ) CPU: 4-core
- 16 GB RAM
- Battery: Health = Normal - Cycle count = 1078
- Intel Iris Pro - VRAM: 1536 MB
- Color LCD 2880 x 1800
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M - VRAM: 2 GB
- macOS High Sierra  10.13.1 (17B48)

Comment: Assuming your Mac is completely up to date, can you run Apple Diagnostics. This will let you know if there are any hardware issues with your device. To access Apple Diagnostics, hold D at boot.

Comment: In addition to AHT as suggested by @Jake3231, I would also try to [stress your MacBook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317786/how-to-stress-a-macbook-pro-retina) to see if you can force it to crash.  If you can replicate it then you should be able to take it in to Apple to replicate it "in house" for them to observe.

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this? The exact thing that is happening to you is happenign to me. I've reset the SMC, also ran apple diagnostics which shows me that all my hardware is just fine. I've checked the log in the console and its nothing ever consistent when its crashing.