# How to stress a MacBook Pro Retina?

Tags: macbook-pro, performance, cpu, benchmark

I need to stress my rMBP components (e.g. CPU/GPU/RAM) without loading any additional software tools.

Background - My rMBP has a hardware fault ([similar to this issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/244241/el-capitan-froze-and-rebooted-macbook-pro-retina-mid-2012)) which causes system freezes that only manifests itself once it has been in use for hours and is under daily load (freezes 4/5 times a day on average) - I can use geekbench which causes the system to freeze quite quickly but want to reproduce the error *quickly* with no 3rd party software installed so to show genius team that the problem can be reproducible of a fresh install of High Sierra & without any 3rd party software installed just to speed up the process of diagnoses & eliminate user error.

Currently I'm watching 4K youtube videos & visiting greensock.com to get Safari to stress & trying to open photos but the machine isn't even noticing the extra load!

Comment: Use the compress option to deal with some files : a couple of fokders full of data...

Comment: Get it a mortgage, credit card debt, a dead end job with a boss who's impossible to please and two kids in private school about to graduate and enter college;  it'll be stressed out in no time.

Comment: You can always try the [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) self-test.

Comment: Posted as a comment since it doesn't really answer the question. But my favorite way to stress-test a Mac is to run BOINC. Run something like SETI@Home on each core plus the GPU. Definitely is 3rd party though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Consuming All the CPU Cores

The command below runs a `yes` instance for each CPU core and consumes a near maximum of the computer's processing capability:

```
CPU=$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)
seq $CPU | xargs -I{} -P $CPU yes > /dev/null
```

The command builds upon [Mike's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/317796/1860), but runs multiple instances of `yes` with [`xargs`](http://offbytwo.com/2011/06/26/things-you-didnt-know-about-xargs.html). One `yes` process will max out a CPU core, so multiple processes are needed. Thanks to @lights0123 for refining this command.

This deals with the CPU but not GPU or RAM.

## CPU + GPU = WebGL

To stress the CPU and GPU, visit [ShibuyaCrowd](http://shibuyacrowd.mattatz.org), a WebGL experiment ([open source](https://github.com/mattatz/ShibuyaCrowd)).

A minute after running this site, your MacBook Pro should be under reasonable computational load.

[image]

Comment: To automatically get the number of cores, `CPU="$(sysctl -n hw.ncpu)" seq $CPU | xargs -I{} -P $CPU yes > /dev/null` will work.

Comment: Thank you. I have added your suggestion into the answer.

Comment: Your `yes` technique will heat the CPU up, but won't really stress it: it barely touches the caches, doesn't do anything with the floating-point calculation units, and for that matter, barely touches the integer-arithmetic circuits.  Unless the fault is somewhere in the small part of the CPU it actually uses, it likely won't cause a freeze.

Comment: @Mark please can you suggest an alternative built-in command? The WebGL link however will reasonably stress the CPU.

Comment: When I run ShibuyaCrowd it can be a bit glitchy for a few seconds at a time. Would you suppose that's saying anything about my PC? https://ibb.co/dR43A7

Comment: @5uperdan please can you [ask this as a new question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You will attract answers this way. Comments tend not to been as widely seen.

Comment: @GrahamMiln "alternative built-in command" `tar` can work.. just find a big folder and compress it to `xz`. It stresses CPU.

Answer (score 11):

Just enter the command `yes > /dev/null` in a Terminal session. That will max out a CPU core until you Ctrl-C it or close the Terminal window.

Comment: For a single core.

Comment: This doesn't come close to heating up your CPU as much as [a Prime95 stress-test](https://www.mersenne.org/download/#stresstest) would.  **Not all "100% CPU" workloads are equal when it comes to how many transistors are actually switching every clock cycle inside the CPU.**

Comment: @PeterCordes can you suggest an alternative built-in command that would exercise the CPU more completely?

Comment: @GrahamMiln: Honestly I'd recommend just downloading Prime95.  IDK what OS X comes with that's seriously computationally intensive.  If it comes with Python + numpy, `octave`, or some other numerical language, then maybe a medium-sized matrix multiply in a loop could do the trick.  The SIMD FP multiply execution units make a lot of heat when they're kept busy.  Oh, video encoding is quite demanding, especially more complex codecs like h.264.  That might do the trick if you have any source data to use.  But don't use GPU-offload (low power fixed-function), you want CPU encoding.

Comment: Thank you for the extra insight. Working with just the built-in macOS commands is limiting. Hopefully @JonnyD20133 will now be able to force the problem for the Apple staff to see.

Comment: @GrahamMiln: `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/null` might keep a CPU busy.  Depending on how multi-threaded the kernel's PRNG is, running it on multiple cores might not help, though.  Even just `awk 'BEGIN { while(1){} }'` will probably do more than `yes`, which spends all its time in system calls.  (And the CPU doesn't make much heat when stalled during user -> kernel transitions.)